# How I can show text in Hindi without circles

Tags: android, fonts, hindi

How I can show text in Hindi without circles between letters 
Text - परीक्षण in application view with circles, sample is - क + ि → कि , but is -  ि क

But in standard settings text view is good.

AndEngine is split words to letters but than do not join this letters to normal words.